# AngularJS - handling error Error: [ng:areq] in this special case (?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

guys.

I've trying to set up an accordion with a directive on angular, but I am getting this error in the console.

```
 Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/ng/areq?p0=CustomDirectivesController&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:6:416
    at Nb (file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:19:417)
    at ob (file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:20:1)
    at file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:75:177
    at file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:57:112
    at r (file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:7:408)
    at I (file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:56:496)
    at g (file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:51:299)
    at g (file:///Users/Marcelo/Desktop/Online-Colleges/capi/view/scripts/angular/angular.min.js:51:316)
```

this is my full AngularJS code

```
customDirectives = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
  customDirectives.directive('customCollapse', function () {
    return {
     require: '?ngModel',
      scope:{
      ngModel: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div class="panel-group" id="{{panelId}}">\
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat-start="item in ngModel">\
    <div class="panel-heading">\
    <h4 class="panel-title">\
    <a ng-click="toggleCollapsedStates($index)" href="#{{panelBaseId}}-{{$index}}">{{item.title}}</a>\
    </h4>\
    </div>\
    <div id="{{panelBaseId}}-{{$index}}" data-parent="#{{panelId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">\
    <div class="panel-body">{{item.content}}</div>\
    </div>\
    </div>\
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>\
    </div>',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.panelBaseId = attrs.collapsePanelBodyId;
      scope.panelId = attrs.collapsePanelId;

      $(document).ready(function(){
        angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function(value, key){
          if (value.collapsed)
          {
            $("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + key).collapse('show');
          }
        });
      });

      scope.toggleCollapsedStates = function(ind){
        angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function(value, key){
          if (key == ind)
          {
            scope.ngModel[key].collapsed = !scope.ngModel[key].collapsed;
            $("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + ind).collapse('toggle');
          }
          else
            scope.ngModel[key].collapsed = false;
        });
      }
    }
  };
});

angular.module('CustomComponents', ['customDirectives']);
function CustomDirectivesController($scope)
{
  $scope.collapseData = [
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 1",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: true
  },
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 2",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: false
  },
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 2",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: false
  }
  ];
}
```

and also my html:

```
<div ng-app="customDirectives">
  <div ng-controller="CustomDirectivesController">
    <div custom-collapse ng-model="collapseData" collapse-panel-id="collapse-panel" collapse-panel-body-id="collapse-panel-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I just checked other questions regarding the same issue, but I see that I did everything properly, can see what is my mistake here?

so, can someone explain me what is going on ?

Comment: use development version of angular for more verbose error output. You will get a stack trace. Minified version gives you links to less verbose erorr output on angular.org

Comment: CustomDirectivesController is a global function not a controller registered to a module in your code. Controllers as global functions were deprecated

Comment: @charlietfl great, but, what I need to do then ?

Comment: `angular.module('CustomComponents').controller('CustomDirectivesController'......`  See [controller docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, actually I just handled this error by setting up the proper controller and dependencies.

In the html everything's fine.

The issue was that I am declaring global functions. Take a look at the new code so will understand:

```
    var customDirectives = angular.module('customDirectives', []);
customDirectives.directive('customCollapse', function () {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    scope:{
      ngModel: '='
    },
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div class="panel-group" id="{{panelId}}">\
    <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat-start="item in ngModel">\
    <div class="panel-heading">\
    <h4 class="panel-title">\
    <a ng-click="toggleCollapsedStates($index)" href="#{{panelBaseId}}-{{$index}}">{{item.title}}</a>\
    </h4>\
    </div>\
    <div id="{{panelBaseId}}-{{$index}}" data-parent="#{{panelId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">\
    <div class="panel-body">{{item.content}}</div>\
    </div>\
    </div>\
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>\
    </div>',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
      scope.panelBaseId = attrs.collapsePanelBodyId;
      scope.panelId = attrs.collapsePanelId;

      $(document).ready(function(){
        angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function(value, key){
          if (value.collapsed)
          {
            $("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + key).collapse('show');
          }
        });
      });

      scope.toggleCollapsedStates = function(ind){
        angular.forEach(scope.ngModel, function(value, key){
          if (key == ind)
          {
            scope.ngModel[key].collapsed = !scope.ngModel[key].collapsed;
            $("#" + scope.panelBaseId + "-" + ind).collapse('toggle');
          }
          else
            scope.ngModel[key].collapsed = false;
        });
      }
    }
  };
})

customDirectives.controller('CustomDirectivesController', function($scope)
{
  $scope.collapseData = [
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 1",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: true
  },
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 2",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: false
  },
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 5",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: false
  },
  {
    title: "Collapse Group Item Title 4",
    content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    collapsed: false
  }
  ];
});
```